# plyer module :: app is not working : it's working in VScode but when i converted into app by pyinstaller the app is opening cmd and closing isntant

Tags: python, windows, module, notifications, reminders

i was creating drinking water program : and run it was working Perfectly  in vs code but after converting into app by using
**pyinstaller --onefile --icon=glass-of-water.ico Water_Time.py
**
its opening cmd and instant closing : i tried  chatGPT also   it gave me solution 2,3 still not working

```
from plyer import notification 
import time


def water():
    while True : 
        notification.notify(
            title = "Water time ",
            message =  "Okay ji  paani pilo  ",
            app_icon  = r"C:\Users\himan\OneDrive\Desktop\python Project build\glass-of-water.ico",
            timeout =  5
        )
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    water()
```

the program is right in visual studio code but  its not working as  a app :) i want this to work as  app